# How do I group by hour in KDB+ Q?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of the form:

```
t                             o      h      l      c      v    
---------------------------------------------------------------
2016.01.04D09:00:00.000000000 105.45 105.45 103.6  103.6  17462
2016.01.04D09:03:00.000000000 103.7  103.99 103.7  103.99 893  
2016.01.04D09:06:00.000000000 103.7  103.7  103.7  103.7  335
```

I want to select the `max o` grouped by hour.

```
select hi: max o by t.date, t.time.hour from z
```

The issue I'm having is that it doesn't seem like `hour` is a valid attribute of `datetime`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hour you can do `time.hh`:

```
select hi: max o by t.date, t.hh from z
```